# why is compareTo(T) taking its argument as Object insted of the the class T that I passed?

Tags: comparable, compareto

I'm trying to use compareTo() in my class but it keeps giving me this error :

```
The method compareTo(T) in the type Comparable<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
```

although a simple casting can fix this error and the code will run fine, I want to now the right way to do it

```
public class BinarySearchTreeImpl<T extends Comparable<T>> implements BinarySearchTree<T>, Iterable{
private Node root;

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return this.root == null;
}
@Override
public boolean insert(T item) throws DuplicateItemException {
    Node newNode = new Node(item);
    if(isEmpty()){
        this.root = newNode;
        return true;
    }
    else{
            Node current = this.root;
            while(current != null){
                if(item.compareTo(current.item) == -1 ){  // The method compareTo(T) in the type Comparable<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Object) 
.
.
.

public class Node<T>{
T item;
Node leftChild;
Node rightChild;
public Node(T item){
    this.item = item;
}
.
.
.
```

If I changed the Node class to `Node<T extends Comparable<T>` I get almost the same error

```
The method compareTo(T) in the type Comparable<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable)
```

Comment: Use the type `Node<T>` instead of `Node` so the compiler knows that the `item` field is of type `T` and not just `Object`.

Comment: @Progman wow that really helped ! thank you!
but could you tell me how is this better than casting to solve this problem ?

Comment: You get type safety during the compilation, so very early in your development. Otherwise you might get an error/exception only later at runtime.

Comment: @Progman I see now. Thanks a lot !